# Can't download Ubuntu - computer thinks its an app

Tags: system-installation

It does download, but when I try to open the download, my computer thinks it is an application and won't start it. I am not very good with computers, but I know that I want off the Microsoft/Windows plantation... please help.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: What file did you download? What version of Ubuntu is it?

Answer (score 2):

What you're downloading isn't an installer, it's a disc image.  You can't run it from within Windows, you have to burn it to a CD/DVD/USB, shutdown your computer, and then boot from it.

Here's instructions for [CD/DVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) and [USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick).

Once you've done that, restart your computer and change the boot priority such that the CD/DVD/USB boots before the hard drive containing Windows does.  You'll then be presented with the Ubuntu installer.  If booting from the media you created becomes troublesome, check [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

Answer (score 1):

Save the file, and then you can [burn it to disc](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), or [a USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), [boot it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install), and then [try it or install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

As Ubuntu is a separate operating system to Windows, you can't open it as an app, you have to run it separately. However, if you are using Windows 7 or earlier, you can use [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).